# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight') at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, html

This message appear at the log of Chrome.

I've tried to use `onclick=` property on `button` tags, but continue with the same error

My code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const act = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible-btn");

    for (i = 0; i < act.length; i++) {
        act[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            const allPanels = document.querySelectorAll(".history-panel");
            allPanels.forEach((panel) => {
                if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
              }
            });
            const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible-btn");
            allButtons.forEach((button) => {button.classList.remove("active");
            });
            let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            let content = panel.nextElementSibling;
            this.classList.toggle("active");

            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend checking out [mcve] as your code is missing an important piece and that is the HTML example. Your code uses `nextElementSibling` but without the HTML, we just have to assume your HTML is in the correct order

Comment: `panel.nextElementSibling;` returns `null` presumably because there aren't any other siblings.

Comment: Please click [edit] and post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

Please delegate and test there IS a nextElementSibling

Alternatively and safer would be to use querySelector from the buttons closest parent container

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentloaded", () => {
  const allPanels = document.querySelectorAll(".history-panel");
  const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible-btn");

  document.getElementById("panelContainer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      const tgt = e.target.closest(".collapsible-btn");
      if (!tgt) return;
      allPanels.forEach(panel => panel.style.maxHeight && panel.style.maxHeight = null);
      allButtons.forEach(button => button.classList.toggle("active", button === tgt));

      let panel = tgt.nextElementSibling;
      if (!panel) {
        console.log("button does not have a panel")
        return;
      }
      let content = panel.nextElementSibling;
      if (!content) {
        console.log("panel does not have content or is not the next element sibling")
        return;
      }
      panel.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is triggered when you are trying to access the scrollHeight property of an element that is null.

The culprit seems to be in these lines:
let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
let content = panel.nextElementSibling;

To fix the error, you should try add null checks:

```
<pre>
    <code> 
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel) {
        let content = panel.nextElementSibling;
        if (content) {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        }
    }
</code>
</pre>
```